# How to copy from DEV SQL Pool to Production SQL Pool

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-pipeline

We have about 300 tables with millions of rows in our Development Azure Dedicated SQL Pool. We want to be able to copy data from the DEV SQL Pool to our Production SQL Pool. One way to do this is to use the BCP tool but we're wondering if there is a better way.

We tried creating a Synapse Pipeline in Production but it won't let us "select" the DEV SQL Pool linked service. Is this even possible to connect from Production Synapse Workspace (that is connected to our PROD SQL Pool) to our DEV SQL Pool?

We tried creating a Synapse Pipeline in Production but it won't let us "select" the DEV SQL Pool linked service.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below approach
As an example I have created a table in DEV Synapse.
I used the Copy activity to load the table in PROD synapse.

- I have created the Azure SQL database as the **SOURCE** and **SINK** dataset.
- In the Linked Service page, you will find a dropdown list where you should choose your server name and the name of your database. After that, you'll need to provide your username and password to establish the connection.

**Source dataset Linked Service:**
[image]

**Sink dataset Linked Service:**
[image]

In the Sink dataset settings, there's an option labeled "**Table**" where you should enable the "**Auto create table**" feature. This will automatically create a table for you with the specified settings.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Know more about [Load data into dedicated SQL pool using the copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/quickstart-copy-activity-load-sql-pool)